# Check if a radio button is checked jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="test" id="test" value="1"><br>
<input type="radio" name="test" id="test" value="2"><br>
<input type="radio" name="test" id="test" value="3"><br>

<input type="button" onclick="CreateJobDo">
```

When the page loads, none of them will be checked. I want to use jQuery to check if one of the radio buttons is checked when the button is pressed.

I have this:

```
function CreateJobDo(){
    if ($("input[@name=test]:checked").val() == 'undefined') {

        // go on with script

    } else {

        // NOTHING IS CHECKED
    }
}
```

But this does not work. How to get it working?

Comment: IDs **MUST** be unique.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit He wants to check if any of his radio boxes are checked, and currently his test statement isn't working.

Comment: Well, maybe you have an old version of the question, because your quote isn't in it? "When the page loads, none of them will be checked. I to use Jquery to check if one of the radio buttons is checked?" - assuming he "wants to use JQuery".

Comment: Sorry, stupid context :) I have a button under it which has to check if one of the radio buttons are checked.

Comment: This asks about radio buttons, and the duplicate question asks about checkboxes.  I (now) know both use the same `:checked` syntax, but it was confusing to confirm it. They should have been left separate questions.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

try this

```
if($('input:radio:checked').length > 0){
// go on with script
 }else{
    // NOTHING IS CHECKED
 }
```

Comment: imo you can safely remove the `> 0` part 'cause positive integers _are_ true

Comment: It works, but it doesn't read as well as `$("input:radio").is(':checked')`.

Answer (score 79):

First of all, have only one `id="test"`

Secondly, try this:

```
if ($('[name="test"]').is(':checked'))
```

Comment: Isnt the name="test" a typo? i believe the right onw is ($('[id="test"]').is(':checked'))

Comment: Don't overthink it. And You'd never do `$('[id="test"]')` you'd do `$('#test')`

Comment: I had the same situation and this answer was the one that help me. I gave my vote. Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

Something like this:

```
 $("input[name=test]").is(":checked");
```

Using the jQuery is() function should work.

Comment: checked works for both radios and checkboxes

Answer (score 11):

```
if($("input:radio[name=test]").is(":checked")){
  //Code to append goes here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  $('#submit_button').click(function() {
    if (!$("input[@name='name']:checked").val()) {
       alert('Nothing is checked!');
        return false;
    }
    else {
      alert('One of the radio buttons is checked!');
    }
  });
```