# Make radio buttons checked /unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$("input[type='radio']").each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).css('background', 'blue');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" data="cool" name="cool" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" data="cool" name="cool">
<input type="radio" data="cool" name="cool">
```

My approach is to first check if my inputs are `:checked` and if they are, put some CSS class with the background color. I achieve that, the next thing I want to is to remove that `:checked` when users click on radio button or any other (better) idea. After the form is submitted, this code checks if inputs are`:checked`, the problem is when I want to select another radio button I get something like this:

[image: a busy cat]

1 and 2 radio buttons are selected, it  should be only 2 `:checked`

Comment: why intending to close this one? the question is fine

Comment: If you have found a solution here, then please select an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the else to remove the blue color like :

```
$("input[type='radio']").each(function () {
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).css('background', 'blue');
   }else{
     $(this).css('background', 'white');
   }
});
```

You could also attach a click event for those radios like :

```
$("body").on("click", "input[type='radio']", function () {
    $("input[type='radio']").css('background', 'white');
    $(this).css('background', 'blue');
});
```

Comment: thank you. Now I can't select the radio button. It set background color to white even if radio is checked="checked"

Comment: now I can select 1 input. I have 15 radio buttons, but with this code I can select only one.

Comment: You've radio button it selects one a time, isn't this what you want?

Comment: I have a form and first off all I need to choose some radio buttons, after that I submit the form. When the page reloads I check if my inputs are: checked, if they are it set background color. That's all fine, but when I want to change the radio button from 1 to 2 I get checked on both radios. Image above.

Comment: Here's the updated fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/z6fLk1pa/ You're not referring in the OP that you have a separated group of radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your JS is that you never remove the class from any of the unselected checkboxes. Also note that `each()` only runs when the page loads (assuming you've not placed it in an event handler, but the question doesn't show that), so you need to instead run your logic in a `change` event handler:

```
var $radio = $("input[type='radio']").on('change', function() {
  $radio.removeClass('blue');
  $(this).toggleClass('blue', this.checked);
});
```

That being said, what you're trying to do can be achieved more simply by using CSS:

```css
input {
  visibility: hidden;
}
input:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #CCC;
  visibility: visible;
}

input:checked:before {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" data="cool" name="cool" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" data="cool" name="cool">
<input type="radio" data="cool" name="cool">
```

Comment: thank you. When the form is submitted, this code does not check if there is: checked to input?

Comment: To do that you can check the number of checked inputs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530582/check-if-a-radio-button-is-checked-jquery

Comment: There are a few more issues too, such as, he hasn't used click/change event, rather he is using each event, meaning that the user has never clicked the radio buttons actually, so how will the right values get submitted after submitting the form.

Comment: Customization and color are secondary.

Comment: Given that the point of the logic in the question is entirely about changing the background of the radio is argue that customisation and color is the entire point. Your point about the use of each is valid though

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I have updated my answer, let me know if I am still missing something.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, basically my question simulates the situation after form is submitted. I have some radios that are checked. This code checks if inputs have :checked and sets background color. The problem is when I want to click on another radio button, this :checked is not removed and I end up with 2 radios that have same color. If you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with your code is that you are using `each` event instead of `change` or `click` event. It means that you are trying to change the color of your radio button, even before user has performed any action. Read the following code, this will solve the issue of submitting the form and also customizing the radio button:

```js
$(".radio-button").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("blue-background");
  $(this).siblings().removeClass("blue-background");
  var radioID = $(this).data('radio');
  $('#' + radioID).attr("checked", "checked");
  if ($('#' + radioID).siblings(":checked")) {
    $('#' + radioID).siblings().removeAttr("checked");
  }
});
```

```css
.blue-background {
  background-color: blue;
}

input[type='radio'] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.radio-button {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <input type="radio" id="radio1" data="cool" name="cool" checked="checked">
  <input type="radio" id="radio2" data="cool" name="cool">
  <input type="radio" id="radio3" data="cool" name="cool">
  <div class="radio-button" data-radio="radio1"></div>
  <div class="radio-button" data-radio="radio2"></div>
  <div class="radio-button" data-radio="radio3"></div>
</div>
```

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: The issue here would be somehow submitting the selected div to a form

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan okay, let me update my answer in that case